# Initialisation method versus constructor plus assignment -- any performance difference? (C++)

Tags: c++, optimization, allocation

I've been programming C++ for a long time so I feel silly for not knowing this but...

I frequently write performance-sensitive code, and when I do I try to avoid heap allocations as much as possible. To that end I often re-use pre-allocated arrays of small objects instead of calling new and delete for each individual object.

In such cases I usually do this:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int x, y;

public:
    inline void Set(_x, _y) { x = _x; y = _y; }
};
```

...

```
MyClass &objectToReuse = someArray[someIndex];

objectToReuse.Set(someXValue, someYValue);
```

However I suspect this better-looking version would generate the same code:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int x, y;

public:
    inline MyClass(_x, _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
};
```

...

```
MyClass &objectToReuse = someArray[someIndex];

objectToReuse = MyClass(someXValue, someYValue);
```

Would a modern C++ compiler "get" this, or would it construct a temporary object and then copy it?

Comment: If your objects are that simple, it makes 0 difference and would likely produce similar, if not equal, **optimized** code. If you have side-effects in your constructors or non-default assignment operator (such as, output or changing external memory) or your objects use virtual functions, then using setter would produce a bit more efficient code. However, I'm quite sure that it won't be the performance problem of your program =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a good compiler will eliminate the extra overhead in this case.

I say "in this case" because it does very much depend on exactly what happens in the constructor (and the assignment operator - where it says "constructor/construction below, read as "or assignment operator"). If the constructor affects (or "might affect") global state, then the compiler can't remove the construction. Affecting global state would be reading or writing files, updating a global variable, almost any call to a function that the compiler doesn't "know" (doesn't have the source code for) will cause the constructor/copy elimination to "fail".

Naturally, if the constructor/copy is not eliminated, the code using a setter may well be more efficient. The exact measure, in a real scenario, can only really be determined by benchmarking, as it's often hard to judge exactly what effect one or many lines of code actually has when compiled with optimisation - something really simple looking can sometimes have quite an impact, where something looking complex can (although less often= ends up not taking much time at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's pretty much what I assumed. Sounds like the constructor/copy elimination would apply to every case in which I do this type of "dumb" class; It's usually vector classes and such which have no bearing on any global state and are completely self-contained.